# JS/TS Non-glob import with prefix

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, glob, es6-modules

I have been doing this all over:

`import * as math from 'mathjs';`

But that leads to the whole MathJS library in my Webpack bundle, so I'm trying to stop using `*` imports.

It is very nice, though, having the `math` prefix when I call a function, e.g. `math.round` or `math.add`. It helps distinguish a bunch of generic function names.

Can I have both named (non-glob) imports, and a prefix for all the functions coming from the same package?

I've tried

`import { add, divide, parse, simplify, round } as math from 'maths';`

But no luck.

Comment: Ran into the same issue today and this is the first question that pops up. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not so far. I ended up going with no prefix :-/